# Extend shopware database, creating relations

Tags: plugins, doctrine, shopware

I'm trying to implement a plugin to add sales representative data to my shop and associate this data to users.

On this context (users and sales representative) I have:

`sales_rep` - Sales representative table
`sales_rep_user` - Relation between User and Sales Representative

1st For the `swg_sales_rep` and `swg_sales_rep_user` relation (OneToMany) I could create that without problems

**SwgSalesRepresentative.php**

```
...
**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="swg_sales_rep")
 */
class SwgSalesRepresentative extends ModelEntity
{
    ...
/**
     * INVERSE SIDE
     *
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(
     *      targetEntity="Shopware\CustomModels\SwagUserSalesRepresentative\SwgSalesRepresentative",
     *      mappedBy="salesRepresentative",
     *      orphanRemoval=true
     * )
     */
    protected $salesRepresentativeUsers;

...
```

**SwgSalesRepresentativeUsers.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="swg_sales_rep_users")
 */
class SwgSalesRepresentativeUsers extends ModelEntity
{

...

/**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Shopware\CustomModels\SwagUserSalesRepresentative\SwgSalesRepresentative")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="sales_rep_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $salesRepresentative;

/**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getSalesRepresentative()
    {
        return $this->salesRepresentative;
    }

    /**
     * @param $salesRepresentative
     * @return ModelEntity
     */
    public function setSalesRepresentative($salesRepresentative)
    {
        return $this->setManyToOne(
            $salesRepresentative,
            '\Shopware\CustomModels\SwagUserSalesRepresentative\SwgSalesRepresentative',
            'salesRepresentativeUsers'
        );
    }
```

And after install I get my tables with foreign key ok.

For the relation between `swg_sales_rep_user` and `s_user` (OneToOne) I have problems. My first idea was extend the `User` model and add the additional logic we need. But this implies to overwrite my users table, take the risk to lose data.
What I did was create a `SwgUser` model that extends User model, like

**SwgSalesRepresentativeUsers.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="swg_sales_rep_users")
 */
class SwgSalesRepresentativeUsers extends ModelEntity
{

...

    /**
     * @var \Shopware\CustomModels\SwagUserSalesRepresentative\SwgUser $user
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Shopware\CustomModels\SwagUserSalesRepresentative\SwgUser", inversedBy="salesRepresentative")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;

 /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * @param $user
     * @return ModelEntity
     */
    public function setUser($user)
    {
        return $this->setOneToOne(
            $user,
            '\Shopware\CustomModels\SwagUserSalesRepresentative\SwgUser',
            'user',
            'salesRepresentative'
        );
    }

...
```

**SwgUser.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="s_user")
 */
class SwgUser extends User
{

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Shopware\CustomModels\SwagUserSalesRepresentative\SwgSalesRepresentativeUsers", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $salesRepresentative;
 ...
```

And `bootstrap.php` install/uninstall looks like

```
 /**
     * Install method
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function install()
    {
        $this->updateSchema();

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Uninstall method
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function uninstall()
    {
        $this->registerCustomModels();

        $em = $this->Application()->Models();
        $tool = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool($em);

        $classes = array(
            $em->getClassMetadata('Shopware\CustomModels\SwagUserSalesRepresentative\SwgSalesRepresentative'),
            $em->getClassMetadata('Shopware\CustomModels\SwagUserSalesRepresentative\SwgUser'),
            $em->getClassMetadata('Shopware\CustomModels\SwagUserSalesRepresentative\SwgSalesRepresentativeUsers')
        );

        $tool->dropSchema($classes);

        return true;
    }


    /**
     * Creates the database scheme from existing doctrine models.
     *
     * Will remove the table first, so handle with care.
     */
    protected function updateSchema()
    {
        $this->registerCustomModels();

        $em = $this->Application()->Models();
        $tool = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool($em);

        $classes = array(
            $em->getClassMetadata('Shopware\CustomModels\SwagUserSalesRepresentative\SwgSalesRepresentative'),
            $em->getClassMetadata('Shopware\CustomModels\SwagUserSalesRepresentative\SwgUser'),
            $em->getClassMetadata('Shopware\CustomModels\SwagUserSalesRepresentative\SwgSalesRepresentativeUsers')
        );

        try {
            $tool->dropSchema($classes);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            //ignore
        }
        $tool->createSchema($classes);
    }
```

I tried to use the [unidirectional](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-unidirectional) association mapping and it creates the field but not the relation with `s_user` table (Foreign key).

So question is, how can I create relations with core tables on shopware without have to recreate (drop/create) the core tables?
Is it possible to alter tables programmatically? what is the best approach for these needs. Do you have an example that demonstrate this?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

there is no way to create bidirectional associations with shopware core tables yet. You can have unidirectional associations for sure, but you will not be able to add relational properties to core entities so far.

Except you intend to modify the shopware core itself which should be avoided at any time.

The only - and very tiny - possibility would be by trying to create a relation over a core entities attribute table which is quite "magic stuff" in shopware.